# How do i center a thumbnail image in a grid gallery, or put entire image as thumbnail

Tags: html, css, gallery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7chd.png

http://pastebin.com/K6htZtJ9

As you can see the image is shifted to the left, i want it to either be centered or the entire image when you click it, how would i be implement that in CSS?

I tried using display: inline-block and display: block.

Comment: Add this style on the parent element to make It centered `margin: 0 auto; max-width: 800px;` That would make the element centered on the screen and the text will also remain in left but f you were to use `text-align: center;` That would make everything centered inside that element. Hope that helps. _-Arqetech_